# uso el método list.count pero siempre me arroja 0 ¿por qué pasa eso?

Tags: python, count

en la función buscarProducto() uso count pero siempre me arroja que hay 0 ¿Por qué pasa eso?
el código busca que los valores ingresados creen un nuevo objeto a partir de la clase Producto, una vez obtenido el objeto el código realiza una consulta, pero quiero saber utilizando **count** cuantas veces se repite un mismo producto para poder saber cuantos hay en existencia.

hasta ahora todo funciona menos el **count**

```
import sys


registro = []

class Producto:
    def __init__(self, p_codB, p_nombreP, p_pesoP, p_precioMay, p_precioMen):
        self.codB = p_codB
        self.nombreP = p_nombreP
        self.pesoP = p_pesoP
        self.precioMay = p_precioMay
        self.precioMen = p_precioMen
        


def registrarProducto():
    print ("Registra los datos del nuevo producto")
    
    codB = int(input("Ingrese el código de barras: "))
    nombreP = input("Ingrese el nombre del producto: ")
    pesoP = (input("Ingrese el peso del producto: "))
    precioMay = (input("Ingrese el precio de mayoreo del producto: "))
    precioMen = (input("Ingrese el precio de menudeo del producto: "))
    


    registro.append(Producto(codB, nombreP, pesoP, precioMay, precioMen))
    return("Producto agregado exitosamente")


def imprimirInventario():
    print("Los productos en existencia son los siguientes")

    for Producto in registro:
        
        print(Producto.codB, ", " , Producto.nombreP, ", " , Producto.pesoP, ", " , Producto.precioMay, ", " , Producto.precioMen)


def buscarProducto():
    print("Buscar un producto")
    codigo = int(input ("ingrese el código de barras: "))

    for Producto in registro:
        if Producto.codB == codigo:
            print(Producto.codB, ", " , Producto.nombreP, ", " , Producto.pesoP, ", " , Producto.precioMay, ", " , Producto.precioMen)
```

*en esta línea de código es en donde quiero hacer uso del count, pero siempre me arroja 0 en la ejecución*

```
    print("Hay ", registro.count(int(codigo)), " en existencia")



def menu():
    op = 0
    salir = 4

    while op != salir:
        print("blah bla opciones")
        op = int(input("Elige opción "))

        if op == 1:
            print(registrarProducto())

        elif op == 2:
            print(imprimirInventario())

        elif op == 3:
            print(buscarProducto())

menu()      
sys.exit()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`registro` es una lista que contiene (o contendrá) instancias de `Producto`. El método `count()` de la clase `list` devuelve las veces que se encuentra dentro de la lista el valor que pases como argumento.

Entonces, como le estás pasando un entero a `count()`, pero la lista `registro` contiene instancias de `Producto`, desde luego te devuelve `0` (porque en efecto no se encontró ningún entero del valor pasado como argumento dentro de ella).

Para mantener las cosas simples, lo que (te sugiero) deberías hacer, es usar la builtin function `sum()`, para sumar 1 cada vez que exista un producto cuyo código coincida con el valor `codigo` que desees.

Sería:

```
product_count = sum(1 for product in registro if product.codigo == codigo)
print("Hay ", product_count, " en existencia")
```

**Aunque...**

Para hacer tu código más eficiente, lo que deberías hacer es realizar el conteo de los productos dentro del `for` donde también estás imprimiendo. Esto, para evitar realizar una nueva iteración sobre `registro` y la redundancia de hacer la misma operación dos veces.

Comment: muchas gracias. me funcionó, Crack.